# Using json values in every class with Flutter?

Tags: json, flutter

I am trying to make an app which will be customize widgets according to a json file from server so, I can do that with my first code with a simple desing, but after trying to make another design such as bottom bar as modal(an opening one) I can't use my data in any class because I can't understand the logic of async, or I think I should use futurebuilder in some how in every widget but I couldn't understand how..
Firstly; is there anyway to get data at first and use this mapped data in every widgets with flutter or what's the optimal answer to my sample?

Working code without desing;

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() async{

  Map data = await getData();
  // String myData = data[0]['title'];
  runApp(new MaterialApp(
    title: 'Random Movie',
    home: new Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.black54,
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey,
        title: new Text('${data['movietitle']}',
            maxLines: 2,
        ),
      ),
      body: new Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 22.0),
        child: new Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            new Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 15.0)),

            new Center(
              child:
              Image.network(data['movieposterurl'],
                height: 300,
                fit:BoxFit.fill
              )
            ),

            new Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 50.0)),
            new Text('Director: ${data['moviedirectors']}',

              style: TextStyle(

                color: Colors.white,
                fontSize: 20.0,
              ),
            ),
            new Text('Genres: ${data['moviegenre']}',

              style: TextStyle(

                color: Colors.white,
                fontSize: 18.0,
              ),
            ),
            new Text('Year: ${data['movieyear']}',

              style: TextStyle(

                color: Colors.white,
                fontSize: 18.0,
              ),
            ),
            new Text('Rating: ${data['movierating']}',

              style: TextStyle(

                color: Colors.white,
                fontSize: 18.0,
              ),
            ),
            new Text('Runtime: ${data['movieruntime']}',
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white,
                fontSize: 18.0,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ));
}

Future<Map> getData() async{
  String myUrl = 'http://127.0.0.1/query?username=username';
  http.Response response = await http.get(myUrl);
  return json.decode(response.body);
}
```

The code I want to design with my data(I need the json data to everywhere I wrote "Data from json",
main.dart

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'modal.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(new MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Random Movie',
      theme: new ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.grey,
      ),
      home: new MyHomePage(title: "Data from json"),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => new _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  Modal modal = new Modal();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: new Center(
        child: new Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            new Text('Data from json'),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: new BottomAppBar(
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            FlatButton(
              onPressed: () {
                modal.mainBottomSheet(context);
              },
              child: Text('Data from json'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
Future<Map> getData() async {
  String myUrl = 'http://127.0.0.1/query?username=username';
  http.Response response = await http.get(myUrl);
  return json.decode(response.body);
}
```

modal.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Modal{
  mainBottomSheet(BuildContext context){
    showModalBottomSheet(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context){
          return Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
            children: <Widget>[
              _createTile(context, 'Data from json', Icons.message, _action1),
              _createTile(context, 'Data from json', Icons.camera_alt, _action2),
              _createTile(context, 'Data from json', Icons.photo_library, _action3),
            ],
          );
        }
    );
  }

  ListTile _createTile(BuildContext context, String name, IconData icon, Function action){
    return ListTile(
      leading: Icon(icon),
      title: Text(name),
      onTap: (){
        Navigator.pop(context);
        action();
      },
    );
  }

  _action1(){
    print('action 1');
  }

  _action2(){
    print('action 2');
  }

  _action3(){
    print('action 3');
  }
}
```

Sample of my json file it change with a python random backend everytime refresh the page with username

```
// 20200309181659
// http://127.0.0.1:5000/query?username=username

{
  "moviecast": "Michael Shannon, Jessica Chastain, Tova Stewart, Shea Whigham, Katy Mixon, Natasha Randall, Ron Kennard, Scott Knisley, Robert Longstreet, Heather Caldwell, Sheila Hullihen, John Kloock, Marianna Alacchi, Jacque Jovic, Bob Maines, Charles Moore, Pete Ferry, Molly McGinnis, Angie Marino-Smith, Isabelle Smith, Tina Stump, Ken Strunk, Maryanne Nagel, Hailee Dickens, Kathy Baker, Guy Van Swearingen, LisaGay Hamilton, William Alexander, Joanna Tyler, Stuart Greer, Ray McKinnon, Jake Lockwood, Kim Hendrickson, Bart Flynn, Nick Koesters, Jeffrey Grover, Qenny O.T. Vitosha, Jason Botsford, Luis Orozco, Joe Zamora",
  "moviedirectors": "Jeff Nichols",
  "moviegenre": "Drama, Horror, Thriller",
  "movieposterurl": "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BNzgzODA5MTU3MF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwODY4MDEwNg@@.jpg",
  "movierating": "7.4",
  "movieruntime": "121",
  "moviesummary": "Curtis, a father and husband, is starting to experience bad dreams and hallucinations. Assuming mental illness, he seeks medical help and counseling. However, fearing the worst, he starts building an elaborate and expensive storm shelter in their backyard. This storm shelter threatens to tear apart his family, threatens his sanity and his standing in the community, but he builds it to save his family's life.",
  "movietitle": "Take Shelter",
  "moviewriters": "Jeff Nichols",
  "movieyear": "2011"
}
```

Final version with url

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
// To parse this JSON data, do
// final payload = payloadFromJson(jsonString);

Payload payloadFromJson(String str) => Payload.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String payloadToJson(Payload data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class Payload {
  String moviecast;
  String moviedirectors;
  String moviegenre;
  String movieposterurl;
  String movierating;
  String movieruntime;
  String moviesummary;
  String movietitle;
  String moviewriters;
  String movieyear;

  Payload({
    this.moviecast,
    this.moviedirectors,
    this.moviegenre,
    this.movieposterurl,
    this.movierating,
    this.movieruntime,
    this.moviesummary,
    this.movietitle,
    this.moviewriters,
    this.movieyear,
  });

  factory Payload.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Payload(
    moviecast: json["moviecast"],
    moviedirectors: json["moviedirectors"],
    moviegenre: json["moviegenre"],
    movieposterurl: json["movieposterurl"],
    movierating: json["movierating"],
    movieruntime: json["movieruntime"],
    moviesummary: json["moviesummary"],
    movietitle: json["movietitle"],
    moviewriters: json["moviewriters"],
    movieyear: json["movieyear"],
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "moviecast": moviecast,
    "moviedirectors": moviedirectors,
    "moviegenre": moviegenre,
    "movieposterurl": movieposterurl,
    "movierating": movierating,
    "movieruntime": movieruntime,
    "moviesummary": moviesummary,
    "movietitle": movietitle,
    "moviewriters": moviewriters,
    "movieyear": movieyear,
  };
}


void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Random Movie',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.grey,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: "Data from json"),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

Payload payload;

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  Modal modal = Modal();
  bool isLoading = true;

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      loadData();
    });
  }

  void loadData() async {
    payload = await getData();
    isLoading = false;
    setState(() {});
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: isLoading
          ? Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())
          : Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(' ${payload.moviecast}'),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            FlatButton(
              onPressed: () {
                modal.mainBottomSheet(context);
              },
              child: Text('Data from json'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

Future<Payload> getData() async {
  String myUrl = 'https://5f0af955.ngrok.io/query?username=lunedor';
  http.Response response = await http.get(myUrl);
  return json.decode(response.body); 
}
//await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 5), () {});

class Modal {
  mainBottomSheet(BuildContext context) {
    showModalBottomSheet(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
            children: <Widget>[
              _createTile(
                  context, payload.moviedirectors, Icons.message, _action1),
              _createTile(
                  context, payload.movierating, Icons.camera_alt, _action2),
              _createTile(
                  context, payload.movietitle, Icons.photo_library, _action3),
            ],
          );
        });
  }

  ListTile _createTile(
      BuildContext context, String name, IconData icon, Function action) {
    return ListTile(
      leading: Icon(icon),
      title: Text(name),
      onTap: () {
        Navigator.pop(context);
        action();
      },
    );
  }

  _action1() {
    print('action 1');
  }

  _action2() {
    print('action 2');
  }

  _action3() {
    print('action 3');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You can use `addPostFrameCallback` and set `bool` `isLoading` 
When `isLoading` is `true`, return `CircularProgressIndicator()`

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      loadData();
    });
  }

  void loadData() async {
    payload = await getData();
    isLoading = false;
    setState(() {});
  }
  ...
  body: isLoading
          ? CircularProgressIndicator()
          : Center(
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
// To parse this JSON data, do
//
//     final payload = payloadFromJson(jsonString);

import 'dart:convert';

Payload payloadFromJson(String str) => Payload.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String payloadToJson(Payload data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class Payload {
  String moviecast;
  String moviedirectors;
  String moviegenre;
  String movieposterurl;
  String movierating;
  String movieruntime;
  String moviesummary;
  String movietitle;
  String moviewriters;
  String movieyear;

  Payload({
    this.moviecast,
    this.moviedirectors,
    this.moviegenre,
    this.movieposterurl,
    this.movierating,
    this.movieruntime,
    this.moviesummary,
    this.movietitle,
    this.moviewriters,
    this.movieyear,
  });

  factory Payload.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Payload(
        moviecast: json["moviecast"],
        moviedirectors: json["moviedirectors"],
        moviegenre: json["moviegenre"],
        movieposterurl: json["movieposterurl"],
        movierating: json["movierating"],
        movieruntime: json["movieruntime"],
        moviesummary: json["moviesummary"],
        movietitle: json["movietitle"],
        moviewriters: json["moviewriters"],
        movieyear: json["movieyear"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "moviecast": moviecast,
        "moviedirectors": moviedirectors,
        "moviegenre": moviegenre,
        "movieposterurl": movieposterurl,
        "movierating": movierating,
        "movieruntime": movieruntime,
        "moviesummary": moviesummary,
        "movietitle": movietitle,
        "moviewriters": moviewriters,
        "movieyear": movieyear,
      };
}

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Random Movie',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.grey,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: "Data from json"),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

Payload payload;

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  Modal modal = Modal();
  bool isLoading = true;

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      loadData();
    });
  }

  void loadData() async {
    payload = await getData();
    isLoading = false;
    setState(() {});
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: isLoading
          ? Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())
          : Center(
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text(' ${payload.moviecast}'),
                ],
              ),
            ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            FlatButton(
              onPressed: () {
                modal.mainBottomSheet(context);
              },
              child: Text('Data from json'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

Future<Payload> getData() async {
  /*String myUrl = 'http://127.0.0.1/query?username=username';
  http.Response response = await http.get(myUrl);
  return json.decode(response.body);*/
  await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 5), () {});

  String jsonString = '''
  {
  "moviecast": "Michael Shannon, Jessica Chastain, Tova Stewart, Shea Whigham, Katy Mixon, Natasha Randall, Ron Kennard, Scott Knisley, Robert Longstreet, Heather Caldwell, Sheila Hullihen, John Kloock, Marianna Alacchi, Jacque Jovic, Bob Maines, Charles Moore, Pete Ferry, Molly McGinnis, Angie Marino-Smith, Isabelle Smith, Tina Stump, Ken Strunk, Maryanne Nagel, Hailee Dickens, Kathy Baker, Guy Van Swearingen, LisaGay Hamilton, William Alexander, Joanna Tyler, Stuart Greer, Ray McKinnon, Jake Lockwood, Kim Hendrickson, Bart Flynn, Nick Koesters, Jeffrey Grover, Qenny O.T. Vitosha, Jason Botsford, Luis Orozco, Joe Zamora",
  "moviedirectors": "Jeff Nichols",
  "moviegenre": "Drama, Horror, Thriller",
  "movieposterurl": "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BNzgzODA5MTU3MF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwODY4MDEwNg@@.jpg",
  "movierating": "7.4",
  "movieruntime": "121",
  "moviesummary": "Curtis, a father and husband, is starting to experience bad dreams and hallucinations. Assuming mental illness, he seeks medical help and counseling. However, fearing the worst, he starts building an elaborate and expensive storm shelter in their backyard. This storm shelter threatens to tear apart his family, threatens his sanity and his standing in the community, but he builds it to save his family's life.",
  "movietitle": "Take Shelter",
  "moviewriters": "Jeff Nichols",
  "movieyear": "2011"
}
  ''';

  return payloadFromJson(jsonString);
}

class Modal {
  mainBottomSheet(BuildContext context) {
    showModalBottomSheet(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
            children: <Widget>[
              _createTile(
                  context, payload.moviedirectors, Icons.message, _action1),
              _createTile(
                  context, payload.movierating, Icons.camera_alt, _action2),
              _createTile(
                  context, payload.movietitle, Icons.photo_library, _action3),
            ],
          );
        });
  }

  ListTile _createTile(
      BuildContext context, String name, IconData icon, Function action) {
    return ListTile(
      leading: Icon(icon),
      title: Text(name),
      onTap: () {
        Navigator.pop(context);
        action();
      },
    );
  }

  _action1() {
    print('action 1');
  }

  _action2() {
    print('action 2');
  }

  _action3() {
    print('action 3');
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your effort, I can use your json sample but when I try to fetch data from my url it just keep waiting data forever, I checked server side and it gets 200 code which means success, I think I made some mistakes while removing your comments, I deleted your json sample then un-comment  /*String myUrl = 'http://127.0.0.1/query?username=username';.....*/" but then "await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 5), () {});" line becomes useless so I deleted that, also when I un-comment "final payload = payloadFromJson(jsonString);" then getting error such as it's used multiple times.

Comment: I added final version which I could understand with a working url if you can check, just fyi url get inactive in every 8 hours but I will update new url when it gets offline, it must be working now.

Comment: please remove return json.decode(response.body); and use return payloadFromJson(response.body);

Comment: because you need to return a Payload instance. so you need to use payloadFromJson

Comment: Thanks again, it's all work now. Just last question, any chance too add "movietitle" to appbar title, when I tired that: "home: MyHomePage(title: '${payload.movietitle}')", it says "movietitle was called on null"

Comment: Silly me, I made it under AppBar that line was title of MaterialApp. All is perfect now, thanks a lot :)